# Downloading files from Azure blob in chunks and merging them back into one csv

Tags: python, azure

I am trying to download a large file using Python from Azure Storage. The file is to large to be loaded all into the memory so I have this.

```
    blob_properties = blob_client.get_blob_properties()
    blob_size = blob_properties['size'] 
    chunk_size = 100 * 1024 * 1024  # 100 MB
    num_chunks = (blob_size + chunk_size - 1) // chunk_size
    for i in range(num_chunks):
        start_offset = i * chunk_size
        end_offset = min(start_offset + chunk_size, blob_size)
        chunk_file_name = os.path.join(dest_folder, f"chunk_{i + 1}.csv")
        with open(chunk_file_name, "wb") as chunk_file:
            blob_data = blob_client.download_blob(offset=start_offset, length=end_offset-start_offset)
            chunk_file.write(blob_data.readall())
```

The only issue is that this results in separate csv files. Is there a way I can merge them all back into one csv? I don't think we can do a simple `pd.concat` because the chunks may contain partial rows.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can open one file and write each chunk to the file.

```
blob_properties = blob_client.get_blob_properties()
blob_size = blob_properties['size'] 
chunk_size = 100 * 1024 * 1024  # 100 MB
num_chunks = (blob_size + chunk_size - 1) // chunk_size
chunk_file_name = os.path.join(dest_folder, "chunk_1.csv")
with open(chunk_file_name, "wb") as chunk_file:
    for i in range(num_chunks):
        start_offset = i * chunk_size
        end_offset = min(start_offset + chunk_size, blob_size)
        blob_data = blob_client.download_blob(offset=start_offset, length=end_offset-start_offset)
        chunk_file.write(blob_data.readall())
```